# why is there a limitation on hard disk size in MBR partitioning?

Tags: partition

> As MBR uses 32-bit to record the partition, each partition can only go
>   up to a maximum of 2TB in size.

How can this be mathematically explained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record):

> [The] maximum disk size supported on disks using 512-byte sectors (whether real or emulated) by the MBR partitioning scheme (without using non-standard methods) is limited to 2 TB.

2TB = 2*1024*1024*1024*1024 = 2^41 = 2^32 * 2^9, and 2^9 is 512.